# regex /ms not behaving as expected perl 5.8.8

Tags: perl

I have a failing test on 5.8.8, I don't understand why, esp when it works in more recent versions (perhaps it was just a bug) (here's a [link to the full code](https://metacpan.org/source/XENO/Dist-Zilla-Plugin-Test-PodSpelling-2.002004/t/dashed.t))

```
use strict;                                                                                                          
use warnings;                                                                                                        
use Test::More;                                                                                                      

my $fname = 'Fo';                                                                                                    

my $content = do { local $/ ; <DATA> };                                                                             
like $content, qr/^$fname $/xms, q[includes first name];                                                             

done_testing;                                                                                                        
__DATA__                                                                                                             
use strict;                                                                                                          
use warnings;                                                                                                        
use Test::More;                                                                                                      

# generated by Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Test::PodSpelling bootstrapped version                                           
eval "use Test::Spelling 0.12; use Pod::Wordlist::hanekomu; 1" or die $@;                                            

add_stopwords(<DATA>);
all_pod_files_spelling_ok('bin', 'lib');
__DATA__
Fo
oer
bar
```

on all recent versions of perl this works fine. but in 5.8.8 the test fails. I found that by removing the `^` and `$` the code works, its like Perls regex engine is ignoring the `/m` but [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlre.html) says it was supported.

Why does this not work? and what is the most correct way to fix it? (note: I believe that the test should check that these elements are on a line by themselves )

Comment: Your question should contain [enough information](http://sscce.org/) to answer it without going offsite to do it.

Comment: @TLP it does I'm just linking full code if someone wants to look at it, unless I'm missing something, but I can't imagine anything else impacting this. Anything more in question would probably be a distraction

Comment: I would argue that it does not. `like` is not any subroutine I know of, and the contents of my TAP is water.

Comment: `like` is part of Test::More which is perhaps the most commonly used module in perl. TAP is the Test Anything Protocol.

Comment: Like I said above: I recommended that you add a [Short, Self-Contained and Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is bug [RT#7781](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=7781). It was fixed in 5.8.9 and 5.10.0.

Workarounds:

- `qr/^/m` is equivalent to `qr/(?:^|(?<=\n))/`
- `qr/$/m` is equivalent to `qr/(?=\n|\z)/`

Comment: Gotta run, but will look for details some more later.

Comment: anyone have suggestions on how they'd deal with this for the test on CPAN?